# django permissions error?

Tags: django, permissions

After trying to add a model entry using the admin interface, I get the following error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/website/app/media/pictures/2.1.0_screenshot.jpg'
```

The thing is, I've already added several items to this folder. How do I correct the permissions, and why would they have changed?

Permissions for that folder:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3967 2012-10-18 13:05 example.png
```

Comment: Could you list the permissions of that folder? `ls -l /dev/website/app/media/pictures/`

Comment: I've added it to the main submission.

Comment: it appears like you pasted the permission for a different image.

Comment: @babbaggeii: like ragsagar said, post the entire output of the command I posted. If the list is large, just purge some entries, but be sure to include a working image, and the faulty image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set permission for user, from what you run you django application.